# Contour Integration of this path circling branch point

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

[image]

If we let the semi-cricle blow up to infinity and the radius of the tiny circle encircling the branch point at origin go to zero, by residue theorem we have:

$$\int_\gamma +  \int_{AB} + \int_{BC} + \int_{CD} + \int_{EF} = 2\pi i \times Residue  $$

Since the function has no residue, RHS = 0.

We know that $\int_{CD} \rightarrow 0$, but how do I show that $\int_{AB} = \int_{EF} \rightarrow 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as in Jordan's lemma [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan's_lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) , you prove that 
$$
\int_{AB}+\int_{EF}\le\pi\frac1{\sqrt{R}},
$$
where $R$ is the radius of the large semicircle.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but I usually use it when the semi-circle is above the real axis..and it's different in this case

Comment: Maybe the change of variable $z=i\zeta$ will make you more comfortable: in the $\zeta$-plane, this semicircle is just above the real axis. Anyway, if you look into the proof you will see that it remains valid in your case.